# Null check operator used on null value flutter couldn't be found

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

We have a screen here supposed to fetch data from firestore cloud but throws this error even though I made sure to check every possible null value but didn't solve the error.

Looks like i am missing out something (value) that i couldn't find
Error is probably at ShowMessages Class

here is the code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GroupScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String groupUID;
  final List  members;
  final bool admin;
  final String title;
  final String username;


   const GroupScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.groupUID,
    required this.members,
    required this.admin,
    required this.title,
     required this.username
});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController _msg = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[300],),
      body:  Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: [
               Text('Messages'),
                ShowMessages(groupUID: groupUID,),
                Row(
                  children: [

                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                              top: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),

                            )
                          ),
                          child: TextField(

                            controller: _msg,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Message...',border: InputBorder.none),
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      if(!_msg.text.isEmpty) {
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").
                            doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).
                            collection("groups").
                                doc(groupUID).
                                  collection("chat").
                                    doc().
                                      set({
                                    "msg": _msg.text,
                                    "user":username


                                        });
                        _msg.clear();
                      }
                    }, icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.deepPurple,))
                  ],
                ),

             ],
            ),
          );
  }
  }

class ShowMessages extends StatelessWidget {
  final String groupUID;
  const ShowMessages({
    super.key,
    required this.groupUID
});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(

    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).collection("groups").doc(groupUID).collection("chat").doc().snapshots(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.data()!.length != null ? snapshot.data!.data()!.length : 0,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            QueryDocumentSnapshot value =  snapshot.data!.data()![index] != null ? snapshot.data!.data()![index] : null ;
            return ListTile(
              title:  Text(value != null ? value['msg'] : ''),
            );
          },
        );
      }
      return Text('');
    } ,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please perform a `null` check before accessing the Firebase `User` object.

In addition, if you are using Visual Studio Code as your code editor, enable uncaught exception, and all exceptions options. It will help you to find the exact line where the error occurred.

Comment: you mean at ShowMessges class where exactly and what should i do

Comment: At which line exactly gets the error thrown? Please mark it in your source.